# Masstransit System.MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: masstransit, saga

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType.GetProperties()'. at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.SqlLockStatementProvider.GetSchemaAndTableNameAndColumnName(DbContext context, Type type, String[] propertyNames) at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.SqlLockStatementProvider.FormatLockStatement[T](DbContext context, String[] propertyNames) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/SqlLockStatementProvider.cs:line 60 at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.SqlLockStatementProvider.GetRowLockStatement[T](DbContext context) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/SqlLockStatementProvider.cs:line 38 at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.PessimisticLoadQueryExecutor`1.GetLockStatement(DbContext dbContext) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/PessimisticLoadQueryExecutor.cs:line 39
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.PessimisticLoadQueryExecutor`1.Load(DbContext dbContext, Guid correlationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/PessimisticLoadQueryExecutor.cs:line 27 at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.PessimisticSagaRepositoryLockStrategy`1.Load(DbContext context, Guid correlationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/PessimisticSagaRepositoryLockStrategy.cs:line 29
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.DbContextSagaRepositoryContext`2.Load(Guid correlationId) at MassTransit.Middleware.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/SendSagaPipe.cs:line 36 at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<<Send>g__SendAsyncCallback|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 67 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<g__Create|0>d.MoveNext() in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 166
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.WithinTransaction[T](DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 callback) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 191
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.WithinTransaction[T](DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 callback) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 210
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.WithinTransaction[T](DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 callback) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 210
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 81 at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /*/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/Saga/EntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 86
at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, Func`3 send) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 87 at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, Func`3 send) in /*/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 96
at MassTransit.Middleware.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/CorrelatedSagaFilter.cs:line 45 at MassTransit.Middleware.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /*/src/MassTransit/Middleware/CorrelatedSagaFilter.cs:line 62
at MassTransit.Middleware.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/TeeFilter.cs:line 40 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at MassTransit.Middleware.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/OutputPipeFilter.cs:line 76 at MassTransit.Middleware.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/OutputPipeFilter.cs:line 108 at MassTransit.Middleware.DynamicFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<g__SendAsync|0>d.MoveNext() in /*/src/MassTransit/Middleware/DynamicFilter.cs:line 89
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.Middleware.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/DeserializeFilter.cs:line 40 at MassTransit.Middleware.RescueFilter`2.MassTransit.IFilter.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RescueFilter.cs:line 43

I try to implement Sagastatemachine